jdk11 IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .sslContext(getSSLContext())
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(connectionTimeoutSeconds))
                    .build();

            HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder();
            headers.forEach(builder::header);
            HttpRequest httpRequest = builder
                    .uri(URI.create(url))
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeoutSeconds))
                    .method(method, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(request))
                    .build();

            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

I try to use java HttpClinet API as above in my product env, sometime I got error response: "IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes" when the request volume is huge
I refer to this problem (OtherDoc), but it does not solve my problem
I want to kown why and how to fix it.
Anybody can help me ?

Just saying it does not solve my problem is not helpful. You are having the exact same issue that the other question that you shared. Did you try every solution suggested in the other question? What were the results of each attempt?

Also did you read the solution by rzwitserloot? It may be that the server doesn't answer and there is nothing to do from your side.

“sometime I got error response” … Edit your question, and include the full stack trace.  Every at line and every Caused by: section.  (As pasted text, not as an image.)
